# Strange menu issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms

Just started out with Orchard and trying to just make pages and menus.

I'm running into an issue where on my home page my menu shows: Home, Fruit, Vegetable, Carrot. I want it to show just Home, Fruit, Vegetable and when I click the respective item it adds the proper tabs. It DOES do it with Banana. ie: When I click Fruit, it shows Banana in the menu. But it always shows Carrot for some reason!

I have the following setup.

```
Navigation
-Main Menu
--Home
--Fruit
--Vegetable
-Fruit Menu
--Banana
-Vegetable Menu
--Carrot

Widgits > Navigation > Main Menu, Fruit Menu, Vegetable Menu
(Fruit and Vegetable Menus are in their own respective layers.)

Path Examples: /Fruit, /Fruit/Banana, /Vegetable, /Vegetable/Carrot
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have 3 menus displayed using 3 different widgets, from which 2 (`Fruit` and `Vegetable` widgets) are displayed only on layers that match specific URLs, right? If so, check if the URL for the layer which contains the `Vegetable` widget is correct and if the widget is actually placed on that layer (which seems to be the case here).